# JOIN SQL queries results in one

Tags: mysql, join, union

I would like to make a query of several select in one, my query works without the last SELECT but with it i have an error which is `Operand should contain 1 column`
Can someone tell me how to correct that ??

---

```
SELECT (
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
) as TOTAL_MSS,
( 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS' AND S = 0 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
) as MSS_S,
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS' AND S != 0 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
) as MSS_F,
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as Nb ,OR as TOP FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS'  AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY OR ORDER BY Nb DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

---

If i execute them separately i get

```
TOTAL_MSS   MSS_S   MSS_F
99          12      87
```

---

```
Nb  TOP
78  j.r@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `UNION` to join the results and second `OR` and `TOP` are keywords so you need to escape them (assuming that you table has a column named OR) :

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as Nb ,
  `OR` as `TOP` 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE 
  TYPE = 'MSS'  
  AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
  AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY 
  `OR` 
ORDER BY 
   Nb DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**Also all queries that are in UNION must have the same amount of fields** and you have for the first 1 field and for the second 2 fields

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(`TOP` = 'one',`Nb`,0)) as first_one,
  SUM(IF(`TOP` = 'two',`Nb`,0)) as second_one,
  SUM(IF(`TOP` = 'three',`Nb`,0)) as thrid_one,
  SUM(IF(`TOP` NOT IN ('three','two','one'),`Nb`,0)) as forth_one,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`TOP` NOT IN ('three','two','one'),`TOP`,'') SEPARATOR '') as `OR`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'one' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'two' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND S=0
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'three' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND S<>0
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      `Nb`,
      `TOP`
    FROM(
      SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb ,
        `OR` as `TOP` 
      FROM 
        mytable 
      WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS'  
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
      GROUP BY 
        `OR` 
      ORDER BY 
         Nb DESC 
      LIMIT 1
    ) as tmp
)as tmp1
```

**UPDATE** the first 3 queries can be resumed to :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(S=0,1,0)) as MSS_S,
    SUM(IF(S<>0,1,0)) as MSS_F,
    COUNT(*) as TOTAL_MSS
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    TYPE = 'MSS' 
    AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Comment: the error is: " the used select statements have a different number of columns "

Comment: @KirkERW well thats strange since all queries from union have 2 column : `Nb` and `TOP`

Comment: @KirkERW sorry i forgot a comma pls try now

Comment: I got a very weird result xD 
Nb  TOP
99  none

Comment: it's not really what i wanted but it works no the problem will be in how to show in php because it doesn't give the result in the format i was awaiting :( but thank you anyway for your help

Comment: np. what format did you expected? `Nb` field is numeric and `TOP` field is string

Comment: i expected to get a table of five columns and one line where there is the results :/

Comment: try now pls and let me know if its what you need

Comment: hey ! x( i just noticed that there's one column that miss :'( where's there's the string j.r@domain.com

Comment: is this in `OR` column from the last query??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29989/discussion-between-kirk-erw-and-stephan)

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
(SELECT 
   1 as rId,
   count(*) as TOTAL_MSS,
   sum(if(S = 0, 1, 0)) as MSS_S,
   sum(if(S <> 0, 1, 0)) as MSS_F
FROM 
   mytable
WHERE
   TYPE = 'MSS' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())) a
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 
       1 as rId,
       COUNT(*) as Nb, 
       OR as TOP 
   FROM 
       mytable 
   WHERE 
       TYPE = 'MSS'  AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
   GROUP BY 
       OR 
   ORDER BY 
       Nb DESC LIMIT 1)b
 ON 
   a.rID = b.rID;
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

USE **UNION** like

```
SELECT_STMT1 UNION SELECT_STMT2 UNION SELECT_STMT3 UNION SELECT_STMT4
```

AS

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
) as TOTAL_MSS UNION
( 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS' AND S = 0 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
) as MSS_S UNION
(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS' AND S != 0 AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
) as MSS_F UNION
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as Nb ,OR as TOP FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'MSS'  AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY OR ORDER BY Nb DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No : / I think it's because I have more than one field in the second one

Comment: by the way the union put the results in one column, what i would like to get is column beside column

Comment: @Gautam3164 it will not work since the first 3 queries have 1 field and the last one has 2